# VBA Sheet code disappears in excel after closing

Tags: vba, excel

Today I've run into a problem, that I'm writing a VBA code for particular sheet in Excel document, but after closing, and opening it, there is nothing and it is not working.

Where could be the problem?
Many thanks

Comment: Which Excel Version? Did you save it? Are Macros enabled?

Comment: MS Excel 2013, I am pressing save button.

Comment: It shows: ms excel the following features cannot be saved in macro-free workbooks

Comment: @user3612205 did you try [googling that phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=ms+excel+the+following+features+cannot+be+saved+in+macro-free+workbooks&oq=ms+excel+the+following+features+cannot+be+saved+in+macro-free+workbooks&aqs=chrome..69i57.272j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)?  There are a lot of answers that you may have found with a little effort:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save your excel file as macro enabled workbook (`.xlsm`)

Comment: xlsb also supports macros